# Prevent auto-import : when copy-paste Java code into Kotlin Android project

Tags: android-studio, auto-import

Facing issue when add copied code from stack-overflow into the android studio and android studio's auto import functionality imports **android.R** package even if it is already imported with our app package name.

Here is steps to reproduce issue.

1) Copy any code from stack-overflow. For example,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

2) Paste it over android studio and below is the output when auto-import performs their operation.

[image]

Above statement will automatically import **android.R** package even if R file not contains R file.

If anyone can help it would be great!

Comment: You really shouldn't copy-paste stuff. You'll end up with a code base you don't understand if you do that.

Comment: @zoe I appreciate your advice but author is addressing this issue with Android Studio.

Comment: @ChintanSoni I'm highly aware, but this is still one of those issues that'll come back to haunt you. It needs to be adressed. And no, it's not an answer - that's why I commented

Comment: @zoe May be it's issue during any settings of android studio or any bug of android studio because it was not happened in previous versions of android studio. I am using 3.3.2 android studio version.